# CRM 2011 :: Converting an email to an opportunity from Outlook

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm

I just want to track an email and wanted to convert the email from my outlook to Opportunity in MS CRM 2011. I was able to achieve this, so far so good.

Now my problem is i have different type of opportunity form and if i need to display any particular for when i create from Outlook i need to capture and event from which i will be able to know this opportunity is being created from Outlook so that in my javascript i can handle that and display a particular type of form i need.

Can i achieve this? 
is there any way which we can get to know through javascript or a code behind that the current Opportunity record which is being create is being created from Outlook?

Please help me in this regard....

Comment: Do you mean Microsoft CRM?

Comment: @Boas Enkler:-   Yes..

Answer (score 0):

You can write plugin and register it on creating new Opportunity. Plugin will set some property of new Opportunity entity instance depending on properties of IExecutionContext like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772178/dynamics-crm-2011-plugin-in-outlook-only).