# Recognize record created from outlook/email in plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, outlook, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I'd like to perform some operation in mscrm plugin, if a new record is created automatically by CRM client for Outlook. Eg. it can be a contact or an incident created from an email.

Is there way to check this condition?

---

We have contact's first name and last name filled oppositely and incident without the caseorigincode field filled, when created from an email in Outlook. Maybe there is a better workarround to solve these two issues. But still I am wondering about the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the sources available online, there is really **no reliable way** to solve this.

There was property CallerOrigin until CRM 4. Then it got deprecated, but continued working for some time, as state in another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14812885/1474519). But it doesn’t seem to be working anymore in CRM 2015.

I found couple advices with `IsExecutingOffline` and `IsOfflinePlayback`, but it is really not solving the problem.

I also found a tip to check this code `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();`. This doesn’t work for me.

I found the most complete information here: http://blog.simpletrees.com/2012/03/executioncontextcallerorigin-in.html
According to this article, I am **sending a value in a hidden field** from my form (or thru API, from plugin, from workflow). As **this field is not set when a record is created from outlook**, I can recognize the record being created from Outlook. There is of course problem, this field might not be set when importing records or when using mobile app. But I don’t see a better way to go.

Therefore, I started request on Microsoft Connect to add this functionality. You can vote for it here: https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/1776771

Answer (score -1):

You could add an attribute to the contact and incident to save the origin of the creation. 
Then you add a plugin that listens to the Create event of the entities and register it only for client side (offline) execution. 
Or you check the **PluginExecutionContext** for the **IsExecutingOffline** and **IsOfflinePlayback** properties to check if the creation was initiated from outlook and store the appropriate value.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.ipluginexecutioncontext_members.aspx

Comment: I don't think this question is regarding an Offline syncing issue.  The plugin context may help here via the "depth" although its not that reliable as depth incrementing can originate from many sources